# correct usage of scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs required versus R code

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am used to doing all my statistics in R and python for all the peripheral tasks. Just for fun I attempted a BFGS optimization to compare it to the ordinary LS result - both in python using scipy/numpy. But the results do not match. I do not see any errors. I also attach the equivalent code in R (which works). Can anyone correct my usage of  scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs to match the OLS or R results  ?

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
from scipy import optimize

class DataLine:
    def __init__(self,row):
        self.Y = row[0]
        self.X = [1.0] + row[2:len(row)]  
        # 'Intercept','Food','Decor', 'Service', 'Price' and remove the name
    def allDataLine(self):
        return self.X + list(self.Y) # return operator.add(self.X,list(self.Y))
    def xData(self):
        return np.array(self.X,dtype="float64")
    def yData(self):
        return np.array([self.Y],dtype="float64")
def fnRSS(vBeta, vY, mX):
  return np.sum((vY - np.dot(mX,vBeta))**2)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    urlSheatherData = "/Hans/workspace/optimsGLMs/MichelinNY.csv"
    # downloaded from "http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~sheather/book/docs/datasets/MichelinNY.csv"
    reader = csv.reader(open(urlSheatherData), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
    headerTuple = tuple(reader.next())
    dataLines = map(DataLine, reader)
    Ys = map(DataLine.yData,dataLines)
    Xs = map(DataLine.xData,dataLines)
    # a check and an initial guess ...
    vBeta = np.array([-1.5, 0.06, 0.04,-0.01, 0.002]).reshape(5,1)
    print np.sum((Ys-np.dot(Xs,vBeta))**2)
    print fnRSS(vBeta,Ys,Xs)
    lsBetas = np.linalg.lstsq(Xs, Ys)
    print lsBetas[1]
    # prints the right numbers
    print lsBetas[0]
    optimizedBetas = sp.optimize.fmin_bfgs(fnRSS, x0=vBeta, args=(Ys,Xs))
    # completely off .. 
    print optimizedBetas
```

The result of the optimization is:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 6660.000006
         Iterations: 276
         Function evaluations: 448
[  4.51296549e-01  -5.64005114e-06  -3.36618459e-06   4.98821735e-06
   9.62197362e-08]
```

But it really should match the OLS results achieved in `lsBetas = np.linalg.lstsq(Xs, Ys)`:

```
[[-1.49209249]
 [ 0.05773374]
 [ 0.044193  ]
 [-0.01117662]
 [ 0.00179794]]
```

Here is the R code in case it is useful (it also has the advantage of being able to read directly from the URL):

```
urlSheatherData = "http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~sheather/book/docs/datasets/MichelinNY.csv"
dfSheather = as.data.frame(read.csv(urlSheatherData, header = TRUE))
vY = as.matrix(dfSheather['InMichelin'])
mX = as.matrix(dfSheather[c('Service','Decor', 'Food', 'Price')])
mX = cbind(1, mX)
fnRSS = function(vBeta, vY, mX) { return(sum((vY - mX %*% vBeta)^2)) }
vBeta0 = rep(0, ncol(mX))
optimLinReg = optim(vBeta0, fnRSS,mX = mX, vY = vY, method = 'BFGS', hessian=TRUE)
print(optimLinReg$par)
```

Comment: Btw, what is your modules versions and system architecture? I didn't manage to optimize successfully with your code on all available combinations (have quite a few in fact). All eneded `Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.`

Comment: I am using Enthought Canopy Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit on Mac OSX 10.6.8, 1.7.1 on numpy and 0.12.0 on scipy.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21055930/scipy-optimize-fmin-bfgs-optimization-gives-different-result-from-simple-functio) is related and basically shows that it is the forced transformation of vBeta that is the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let's make arrays out of list:

```
>>> Xs = np.vstack(Xs)
>>> Ys = np.vStack(Ys)
```

Then, `fnRSS` is incorrectly translated, it's argument, beta, is passed transposed. Can be fixed with

```
>>> def fnRSS(vBeta, vY, vX):
...     return np.sum((vY.T - np.dot(vX, vBeta))**2)
```

Final result:

```
>>> sp.optimize.fmin_bfgs(fnRSS, x0=vBeta, args=(Ys,Xs))
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 26.323906
         Iterations: 9
         Function evaluations: 98
         Gradient evaluations: 14
array([-1.49208546,  0.05773327,  0.04419307, -0.01117645,  0.00179791])
```

Sidenote, consider using pandas [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) parser or numpy [`genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) or `recfromcsv` to read csv data into array instead of custom written parsers. No problems to read from url either:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> urlSheatherData = "http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~sheather/book/docs/datasets/MichelinNY.csv"
>>> data = pd.read_csv(urlSheatherData)
>>> data[['Service','Decor', 'Food', 'Price']].head()
   Service  Decor  Food  Price
0       19     20    19     50
1       16     17    17     43
2       21     17    23     35
3       16     23    19     52
4       19     12    23     24

[5 rows x 4 columns]
>>> data['InMichelin'].head()
0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
Name: InMichelin, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for the csv tip, that is useful.