# scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs optimization gives different result from simple function call

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am exploring some of the numpy/scipy functions and I noticed that scipy.optimize.fmin_bfgs requires a change in the function being called to give correct results compared to a straight function call. My first definition of the `fnRSS` function returns a correct value when calling the function but refuses to work in the optimization; my second definition gives the wrong result when calling the function but the right one when running the optimization. Can someone tell me what is so crucial about transposing the `vY` parameter for the optimization ? It should already be 164x1.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp
import pandas as pd
from scipy import optimize

if __name__ == "__main__":
    urlSheatherData = "http://www.stat.tamu.edu/~sheather/book/docs/datasets/MichelinNY.csv"
    data = pd.read_csv(urlSheatherData)
    Xs = np.vstack(data[['Service','Decor', 'Food', 'Price']].values)
    Xs = np.concatenate((np.vstack(np.ones(Xs.shape[0])),Xs), axis=1)
    Ys = np.vstack(data[['InMichelin']].values)
    # optimal solution (given)
    vBeta = np.array([-1.49209249,  -0.01117662,  0.044193, 0.05773374, 0.00179794]).reshape(5,1)

    print Ys.shape, Xs.shape, vBeta.shape 
    # first definition of function
    def fnRSS(vBeta, vY, mX):
      return np.sum((vY - np.dot(mX, vBeta))**2) 
    print fnRSS(vBeta, Ys, Xs) # correct value
    print np.linalg.lstsq(Xs, Ys)[1] # confirm correct value
    print sp.optimize.fmin_bfgs(fnRSS, x0=vBeta, args=(Ys,Xs)) # wrong value
    # second definition
    def fnRSS(vBeta, vY, mX):
      return np.sum((vY.T - np.dot(mX, vBeta))**2) 
    print fnRSS(vBeta, Ys, Xs) # incorrect value
    print sp.optimize.fmin_bfgs(fnRSS, x0=vBeta, args=(Ys,Xs)) # correct convergence but simple call gives different value
```

My output:

```
(164, 1) (164, 5) (5, 1)
26.3239061505
[ 26.32390615]
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: 6660.000000
         Iterations: 39
         Function evaluations: 3558
         Gradient evaluations: 480
[  4.51220111e-01   1.32711255e-07   8.09143368e-08  -1.06633003e-07
  -5.18448332e-08]
9002.87916028
Warning: Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.
         Current function value: 26.323906
         Iterations: 29
         Function evaluations: 1954
         Gradient evaluations: 260
[-1.49209095 -0.0111764   0.04419313  0.05773347  0.00179789]
```

Comment: as followup on alko: just play with dot and see what shape you get when vBeta is 1-D versus a column array. np.dot broadcasts/transposes a 1d array if needed, but the shape and ndim are different. Y needs to match your vBeta.ndim

Comment: Thanks, I will play around with that. I guess I do not like the fact that you have to optimize on a function that gives the wrong return when you test out the result of the optimization - that kills a lot of unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not about `vY.T`, but `vBeta`, i.e. `x` being passed by `fmin_bfgs` to `fnRSS` as not a 2d vector but a 1d array. So despite the fact you explicetely try to specify `x0=vBeta` to be an array of shape (5,1), it is converted internally to 1d array of shape (5, ), and in the end is returned as such.

Comment: I see what you mean and I can see that happening when I put `print vY.shape, mX.shape, vBeta.shape` inside of the `fnRSS` function but I don't see how that would mess up the convergence or require `vY.T`. Don't get me wrong you are probably right, because it works but in the first definition you should get a `(164,1)-(164,)` inside the first brackets but the second definition should give `(1,164) - (164,)` which should not compute yet it does.